# Como acrescentar linhas em branco no retorno de uma query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma `Query` que a cada consulta retorna uma quantidade de linhas diferentes, porém preciso que essa mesma query retorne sempre 10 linhas, mesmo que essas linhas sejam nulas, exemplo:

```
Select ID, NOME From tab1;
```

---

```
00 | ID   | NOME
01 | 01   | JOÃO
02 | 02   | MARIA
03 | 03   | PAULO
04 | null | null
05 | null | null
06 | null | null
07 | null | null
08 | null | null
09 | null | null
10 | null | null
```

Observação: poderia resolver isso no código da aplicação,  mas por outros motivos devo fazer isso no Banco de Dados

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523036/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-isnull-function

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php

Comment: Select rownum "00" , id,max(nome) nome from (Select ID, NOME From tab1 Union Select level id,null nome from dual connect by level < 11) aux group by id .... gerando uma sequencia artificial nula. Sem teste todavia

Comment: Bom dia!, perfeito @Motta problema resolvido, esse código vai permitir colocar em implantação uma solução que o cliente estava aguardando a mais de 1 ano e outros profissionais não consiguiam resolver, obrigado esse post vai ajudar outros profissionais.,

Comment: Resolvido. Créditos ao [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta) .